# How to make an if statement condition in RecyclerView

Tags: android, if-statement, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

How to make a sample of an if statement like:
        if my recyclerview list has some textview string "customer". Then I want to disable the editext in all recyclerview list that has a textview string customer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly (How to disable the EditText for the ViewHolders that contain the text "customer") then...

You will need to perform the check in the `onBindViewHolder(...)` method.

e.g.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Represents how you are performing data storage, yours will most likely be different
    DataObject dataObject = getItem(position);

    //NOTE: comparing strings like this can cause errors, especially in cases where the display text should be localized
    boolean isCustomer = dataObject.getTypeText().equalsIgnoreCase("customer");

    //Sets the text and hides/shows the EditText
    holder.customerView.setText(dataObject.getTypeText()); //Should be a string resource, or correctly localized
    holder.editText.setVisibility(isCustomer ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}
```

This comes from the idea that you only ever make the max amount of views that will be displayed on the screen at any moment, and reuse them as necessary (bind them).

Comment: How was it , the onBindViewHolder is never used ,  i also did earlier the setVisibility and setEnable but nothings happened . Maybe i have a problem on my holder ,

Comment: As long as you have specified the LayoutManager and the adapter has items, `onBindViewHolder(...)` should get called.  Also, you should post your calling code so that we (the community) can better help you